# React Native Mapped Components - Unexpected Token

Tags: react-native

I'm attempting to go through the example found in the React Native in Action book, and found that I cannot for the life of me get this particular portion to function.

```
class Books extends React.Component<{}> {
    render() {
        const { books } = this.props

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>Books</Text>
                <ScrollView
                    keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'
                    style={styles.booksContainer}
                >
                    {
                        books.map((book, index) => (
                            <View style={styles.book} key={index}>
                                <Text style={styles.name}>{book.name}</Text>
                                <Text style={styles.author}>{book.author}</Text>
                            </View>
                        ))
                    }
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

The issue I'm running into is an unexpected token:

```
2019-01-22 10:26:24.022929-0700 0x16165    Default     0x0                  22625  0    RNRedux: Failed to load bundle(http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false) with error:(SyntaxError: /Users/buddy/Documents/react-native-begin/RNRedux/node_modules/react-native/src/Books.js: Unexpected token, expected "}" (28:26)

\^[[0m \^[[90m 26 | \^[[39m                            \^[[33m<\^[[39m\^[[33m/\^[[39m\^[[33mView\^[[39m\^[[33m>\^[[39m\^[[0m
\^[[0m \^[[90m 27 | \^[[39m\^[[0m
\^[[0m\^[[31m\^[[1m>\^[[22m\^[[39m\^[[90m 28 | \^[[39m                        ))\^[[33m;\^[[39m\^[[0m
\^[[0m \^[[90m    | \^[[39m                          \^[[31m\^[[1m^\^[[22m\^[[39m\^[[0m
\^[[0m \^[[90m 29 | \^[[39m                    }\^[[0m
\^[[0m \^[[90m 30 | \^[[39m                \^[[33m<\^[[39m\^[[33m/\^[[39m\^[[33mScrollView\^[[39m\^[[33m>\^[[39m\^[[0m
\^[[0m \^[[90m 31 | \^[[39m            \^[[33m<\^[[39m\^[[33m/\^[[39m\^[[33mView\^[[39m\^[[33m>\^[[39m\^[[0m (null))
```

This seems to happen anytime I'm trying to map in a set of Components.  Any idea what/where I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it had nothing to do with the code itself - kind of.

Previously, I had an invalid semicolon after the map function like this:

```
books.map((book, index) => (
    <View style={styles.book} key={index}>
        <Text style={styles.name}>{book.name}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.author}>{book.author}</Text>
    </View>
));
```

While I had found that mistake myself, for whatever reason the version on the simulator would not refresh no matter what I would do.  After deleting the app fully from the simulator and rebuilding it, the issue was resolved.

Moral of the story: try rebuilding!

Answer (score -1):

I see you are using `ScrollView` and inside `ScrollView`, You always have to use a single child.

You could try something like this.
and also try to change `React.Component<{}>` to just `React.Component`,

```
class Books extends React.Component {
render() {
    const { books } = this.props

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>Books</Text>
            <ScrollView
                keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'
                style={styles.booksContainer}
            > 
             <View>
                {
                    books.map((book, index) => (
                        <View style={styles.book} key={index}>
                            <Text style={styles.name}>{book.name} 
                          </Text>
                            <Text style={styles.author}>{book.author} 
                        </Text>
                        </View>
                    ))
                }
               </View>
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
    )
}
}
```

Comment: A good note, but this doesn't help with the issue unfortunately.

Comment: A negative to the second change as well.

Comment: Can you implement it on Expo Snack? so that i could see whats wrong